# Java lib to compare two text files with support of wildcard

Tags: java, wildcard, text-comparison

I am creating autotest using Selenium. Outcome of the test is report file which I need to compare with expected one. Is there a way to compare to text files in Java? I would like to use wildcards to mask some data.
I looked at [ApprovalTests](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Java) but it seems that it does not support wildcards

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/index.html). From their web site:

> Apache LuceneTM is a high-performance, full-featured text search
>   engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable
>   for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially
>   cross-platform.

And [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) you can get a bit detail of wildcard searching. 
And [here](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) some tutorials you might find useful.

Comment: It looks like Lucene is too big hammer for my tiny nail...but thank you anyway